# If I frequently ORDER BY o.creationDate - should I mark creationDate with @Index?

Tags: sql, mysql

I know that indexes on database are a good way to increase query performance, but how much performance I would gain by creating an index for a creationDate property of a given object that I frequently order by creationDate in my queries? Would this frequently "order by o.creationDate" justify creating an index for the creationDate property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the result set returned from your select is large. Remember that the ordering is (logically) performed on the result set after filtering, but a good optimizer might use an index during filtering for ordering as well. If you are returning a results set with five rows, ordering is trivial. If it contains a million rows, a (B-Tree based) index would definitely help. A hash-index would be of no help, however.

You can get more details with regard to MySQL and indexes for ORDER BY columns from the following article: [Database Index Tips](http://www.websitedatabases.com/database-index.html)

Comment: Wouldn't it iterate just over the result set ? Should I create an index for this property even if system uses this property just after having a result set on hand ?

Comment: @user430830 - This answer isn't really accurate, since the benefit of the index on the column is that it *wouldn't* order after the filtering, it'd order as *part of* the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your read/write ratio as to if it's justified, but will it help? From your usage description yes, an index on `creationDate` will allow it to run the query without an extra sort operation at the end on it.  [You can find a full write-up on `ORDER BY` optimization here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

I'd say if this is a web application or any other high read:write ratio application then *yes*, it's worth it.  Just remember that indexes do have a cost, and inserts or updates on that column will be more expensive when it's added, but when your reads far outweigh the writes, it's *usually* worth it.

Comment: Would you create indexes login AND for password fields for a table User? Imagine it is a web application where you have at least 200 users authenticating to the system every day and at least 60 registering everyday.

Comment: @user430830 - If you're authenticating (filtering) by them, yes...make sure you're not storing the passwords in plaintext though, they should be a hash/encrypted form of some sort.

Comment: yeah.. thanks could realize how it would help me.. and yes the passwords are not in plain text :)